# Vscode python intellisense not working when storage is over 1-2TB

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, storage, intellisense

As my dataset is growing larger, python intellisense begins to not responding.

changing the working directory in settings.JSON might work as one of the solution, however, I want to reside my dataset inside of the project directory.

Is there any option that I might can do??

Comment: is your dataset stored in Python files

Comment: @rioV8 No, it is just img, pcd, and json files

Comment: why would that type of files slow down PyLance? Is the number of files very large? Is it possible to ignore certain directories in PyLance, if not you could create an isue at the PyLance repo

Comment: @rioV8 whenever I delete those files, intellisense works perfectly fine, yet whenever I download them, autocomplete suddenly stops and only shows loading.

Comment: I would recommend you put a large dataset in a separate location, not in the "project" space, where your code lives.

Comment: no need to delete and download them again, just move to a different location and move back

Comment: @topsail thank you for the advice. I am currently replicate other project and their code base requires to put data inside of the project. I might be able to fix some of their directory setup code.

Comment: That's interesting - for such a large dataset this is like having an entire database with billions of records in your "code" ... that is almost certainly a bad idea. What kinds of reasons do you see in this "other" project for doing this? For one thing, it will make version control a nightmare. Also it will definitely slow down your tools in your ide (code analysis, intellisense, build/publish).

Comment: @topsail thank you for your help! I was replicating one of the code from top conference paper and their guideline asked to put 600GB img and other files inside of the project itself to generate .pkl.  It is my first time handling those kind of big data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found answer:

In settings.JSON

```
    "python.analysis.exclude": [
        "**/data/**",
        "**/experiments/**",
        "**/wandb/**"
    ]
```

put the data folder name you want to exclude from analyzed by Pylance.

source: [Vscode: can't go to definition due to large workspace (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415909/vscode-cant-go-to-definition-due-to-large-workspace-python)

Comment: Hi Park Bo, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Thank you for reminder! I can only accept my own answer in 13 hours. I will do it after that